# I cannot display a value in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

The "id" string in this function has a value but it is not displayed in the label. I have a break point there and I can clearly see such value.

```
protected void RadTreeList1_ItemCommand(object sender, TreeListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string id = "";
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem)
        {
            TreeListDataItem item = e.Item as TreeListDataItem;
           id = item.GetDataKeyValue("MessageID").ToString();
        }
    }
    Label2.Text = id;
}
```

**UPDATE**
and does not work also like this:

```
....
string id = item.GetDataKeyValue("MessageID").ToString();
Label2.Text = id;
```

Any suggestion about the possible reason?

Comment: Are you calling it again with a different e.CommandName before it has a chance to be displayed, thus setting Label2.Text to ""? What happens if you move the assignment of Label2.Text just after the assignment of id?

Comment: @DouglasZare Label2 is only in this method. Initially I tried to assign the value to the label just after the id=.... but is the same. It does not display. The label is in the form runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this Put  Label2.Text = id; in   if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem)

protected void RadTreeList1_ItemCommand(object sender, TreeListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string id = "";
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        if (e.Item is TreeListDataItem)
        {
            TreeListDataItem item = e.Item as TreeListDataItem;
             id = Convert.ToString(item.GetDataKeyValue("MessageID")) ;
            Label2.Text = id;
        }
    }

}
```